# Mvc php validation data

Tags: php, forms, model-view-controller

I am developing a simple php application with MVC architecture. My model is a user and view is simply a form render. Before submitting data by form to db I want to validate fields form and print if there are errors. Where can I put my validation function, in view or in model?

Comment: Models are used for database interaction, so the model.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the dupes? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499499/where-to-validate-and-process-form-submission-in-mvc-website?rq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305854/best-place-for-validation-in-model-view-controller-model?rq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831442/where-is-the-best-place-to-verify-form-data?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MVC applications, you interact with the database in models. Therefore, if you need to validate your form input with the database, you should do this in a model.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your form fields in your `model`. Alternatively, you might want to use front-end validation with Javascript or JQuery. In this case, you should put your js code to `view`.